# Send post request to django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I'm trying to send a post request with file by using fetch api to django rest framework.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^lead/$', views.LeadListCreate.as_view()),
    url(r'^test/$', views.test, name='test')
]
```

views.py

from rest_framework import generics
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
    from rest_framework.response import Response

```
from api.models import Lead
from api.serializers import LeadSerializer, FileUploadFuelSerializer


class LeadListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LeadSerializer


@api_view(['POST'])
def test(request):
    print(request.data)
    print(type(request.data['file']))
    serializer = FileUploadFuelSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # serializer.save()
        print('ok')
        return Response({'res': 'Everything's ok'})
    print(serializer.errors)
    return Response({'res': 'none'})
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Lead, FileUploadFuel


class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'


class FileUploadFuelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUploadFuel
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Lead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class FileUploadFuel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='fuel/')
```

My request

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let body = new FormData()
    body.append("file", this.state.file)
    fetch("/api/test/", {
        body,
        headers: new Headers({
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
        }),
        method: "POST"
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.status)
        return res.json()
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

When I send request by using postman, it works.

And the type of request.data['file'] is

```
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
```

The problem:

When I send request by using fetch api, it doesn't work as I would like to.
The type of request.data['file'] is

```
<class 'str'>
```

How can I fix that problem in order to get a InMemoryUploadedFile object and not str ?

Comment: can you check whether the file is present in request.FILES or request.body ? since it is a formData. it may not be present in request.data.

Comment: I printed request.data, request.POST and request.FILES they're all empty. I think the problem is my fetch request because as I said above everything works when I use Postman.